# JPA Criteria API Join

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

How would I translate this JPQL query into Criteria API?

```
select count(p) from Person p join p.glanceList g where p.duration < 1000 and g
.duration < 1000
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one.

```
CriteriaQuery<Long> q = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<Person> person = q.from(Person.class);
Join<Person,Glance> glance = person.join("glanceList", JoinType.INNER);
q.select(cb.count(person))
.where(cb.lt(person.get("duration"), 1000), cb.lt(glance.get("duration"), 1000));
```

Assuming `Glance` is the class of the entity in the join.

And

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
```

Comment: Where does `order` come from?

Comment: Good catch, based on the context I think that should be `person`, the join method is part of the existing method in the `Root` object

Comment: Thank you Koitoer - I couldn't find any official documentation showing how to get an attribute of a joined entity (Glance in this case).