# JPA Criteria API: JOIN - Why is join object not usable for both involved entities?

Tags: jpa, join, where-clause, criteria-api

there is something about the JPA Criteria API's Join which I don't get in my mind and didn't find any explanation. Fist I will show the wrong, then the correct implementation and then the questions regarding the wrong approach.

Let's assume we have the following situation:
EntityA has a @ManyToOne relation to EntityB. And I want to join them and filter entities based on both entities' attributes.

So we have a root of EntityA and we join this entity with EntityB.
The following approach shown is giving some error as you can see:
[image]

If we take a closer look on the returned Join object we see this. I can only use the target type (=EntityB)'s attributes on that Join object:
[image]

And the correct way would be this (using EntityA's Root object instead of the Join object):
[image]

Questions:

1. For my understanding I'd say that if this Join object represents the two joined tables EntityA and EntityB (= a new combined table with all of their attributes/columns) then I should be able to the Join (and only that one) to create where-clauses which filter for attributes ***of both involved entities***.
   But it seems I cannot create where-clauses on that join for attributes of EntityA (the source type of the Join), only for EntityB (the target type of the Join).
   Why is that so? It's confusing me. Unfortunately it's nowhere stated or explained (JEE / Hibernate documentation) that a Join object can only be used this way or why it works like this.
   I mean if I write this down in SQL it would probably look like this:
   SELECT ... FROM EntityA a join EntityB b ON a.joinColumn = b.id WHERE a.year='value' AND a.weeks=5 AND b.family='value' AND b.country='GB'
   and that is clear and not confusing. Here I clearly specify which attribute from which entity is involved. Another example: [JPA Criteria API Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490664/jpa-criteria-api-join)

   - *Further lines of thought:*
     I don't really know about the DB behaviour in the background, but...
     a) Let's assume the DB is evaluating the where clauses first on its individual entities/tables and then joining the remaining matching entities: Using JPA Criteria API why do I have to create a where clause on the Root object of EntityA while for the EntityB I have to use the join object to do the same? I just want to point out that it does not look consistent of what I do in SQL and this confused me. (I know that if I would also create a Root object for EntityB and apply where clauses on that root object I could make it "look" consistent to the SQL way but would end up in a cartesian product/cross join by doing that)
     b) And if we assume the opposite it leads me to the origin question: Let's assume the DB is first joining the tables and then applying the filtering/where clauses: When using JPA Criteria API why can't I work (i.e. define where clauses) only on the join object then?
2. That also leads me to the question: What actually does the returned Join object represent? It is typed with <EntityA, EntityB>. What is the "source type" and "target type"? As stated above I can only use it for EntityB.

Somewhere I am stuck with my way of thinking it seems. I appreciate bringing me back to the right track.

Comment: You are mistaken on what the 'join' object is. It is NOT a combination of entities, but a reference object giving you access to the joined entity. JPA criteria queries are entity based -so your criteria query is traversing your model and you've explicitly defined a join over the entityA.joinColumn relationship. IN your query root==EntityA while Join == EntityBs referenced from EntityA. This is akin to JPQL "SELECT root from EntityA root join root.joinColumn entityB where root.year = :year AND root.week = :week AND entityB.family = :family AND entityB.country = :country"

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken on what the 'join' object is. It is NOT a combination of entities, but a reference object giving you access to the joined entity. JPA criteria queries are entity based -so your criteria query is traversing your model and you've explicitly defined a join over the entityA.joinColumn relationship. IN your query root==EntityA while Join == EntityBs referenced from EntityA. This is akin to JPQL "SELECT root from EntityA root join root.joinColumn entityB where root.year = :year AND root.week = :week AND entityB.family = :family AND entityB.country = :country"

Joins, inner joins specifically, are the default and do not need to be explicitly defined. You can access 'week' from EntityB directly using JPQL:

> SELECT entityA from EntityA entityA where entityA.joinColumn.week = :week"

The `entityA.joinColumn` forces an inner join according to the specification and would result in the same SQL as

> SELECT entityA from EntityA entityA join entityA.joinColumn entityB where entityB.week = :week"

Criteria query follows 1:1 with JPQL for the most part, but can be confusing because of the abstraction. Generic and type safety on Join<EntityA, EntityB> allows compile time checks that you are only accessing properties of EntityB within it, so you don't confuse it with some other join on EntityC, or that the root is of some other type.